# Issue with making a list a string, keep getting an error that it's a list when i use a method for a string, how can i solve this?

Tags: python, string, list, function, python-3.5

My code is:

```
import sys

filename = sys.argv[1]

def make_header(genbank_file):
    openfile = open(genbank_file)

    for new_line in openfile:

        if new_line.startswith("DEFINITION",):
            definition_string = new_line

        if new_line.startswith("VERSION"):
            version_string = new_line

        if new_line.startswith("ACCESSION"):
            accession_string = new_line

    definition_string = definition_string.strip("DEFINITION")
    definition_string = definition_string.strip(" ")

    version_string = version_string.replace(" ","")
    version_string = "".join(version_string)

    for char in str(version_string):
        version_string = version_string.split(':',1)[1:]

    header = ">gi|" + version_string + accession_string + definition_string

    return header


print(make_header(filename))
```

I'm not sure why the variable `version_string` is not a string, it should be one automatically since it was taken from a text file if I'm not mistaken, but I've tried to use `version_string = str(version_string)`, and `version_string = "".join(version_string)`, yet even after that I still get the error:

```
version_string = version_string.split(':',1)[1:]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

has `version_string` somehow become something I can't turn into a string?
When I print it it shows `VERSIONNG_012637.1GI:255652911` since the spaces were removed.

Comment: Instead of adding "solved" to the question just [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer that helped you solved this or if you found the solution yourself (and it differs significantly from the existing answers) then you can also [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
version_string = version_string.split(':',1)[1:]
```

You have this line *inside a loop*, and it changes the value of `version_string`.

The first time it is indeed a string, but `.split()` returns a list and `[1:]` gives part of that list, so after the first time it is a list.

You should probably change it to `[1]` instead of `[1:]`, as that gives the first element of the split, which is again a string.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response, it has been fixed now, i did not realise that function was the one who turned it into a list, i thought it gave an error because it was a list before that, my thanks.